# How do you generate a solana address with private key using javascript?

Tags: address

I want to create a paper wallet for solana addresses. But how do I generate the address and private key for Solana using javascript? Is there a simple library I can use without all the extra bells and whistles? I just want to generate an address and private key that's it.

Comment: Did you try looking in the Solana cookbook?

Comment: https://solanacookbook.com/getting-started/installation.html#macos-linux

Comment: Yes that's it. Did you try https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-generate-a-new-keypair ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate a keypair with the [@solana/web3.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana/web3.js) library. Per the [Solana Cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-generate-a-new-keypair):

```
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";

let keypair = Keypair.generate();
```